# linq doesn't iterate over list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I've written the following code

```
List<Pupils> pupils = PupilsDAO.SelectDAO();
XElement dtpupil = new XElement("DtDatas",
                from xlist in pupils
                orderby xlist.Id
                    select new XElement("DtData",
                        new XElement("ref", xlist.Id),
                        new XElement("forename", xlist.Forename),
                        new XElement("surname", xlist.Surname)
                    )
            );
```

rather than getting a different XML object for each element in the list, I do get an output for every item in the list, but they're all the same rather than actually iterating through the, so just loads of say...

```
<DtDatas>
   <DtData>
      <ref>01</ref>
      <forename>joe</forename>
      <surname>bloggs</surname>
   </DtData>
 <DtData>
      <ref>01</ref>
      <forename>joe</forename>
      <surname>bloggs</surname>
   </DtData>
 <DtData>
      <ref>01</ref>
      <forename>joe</forename>
      <surname>bloggs</surname>
   </DtData>
 <DtData>
      <ref>01</ref>
      <forename>joe</forename>
      <surname>bloggs</surname>
   </DtData>
</DtDatas>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?  Am I meant to add an iteration for the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've presented is fine. That suggests that the data in your list is incorrect. Possible options:

- You're adding the same reference to the list multiple times, and just mutating the same object repeatedly within whatever loop is constructing the list.
- You're using static variables to back the properties

If you can post the `Pupils` class and the `SelectDAO` method, we should be able to help more.

Comment: Are you sure there is no `access-to-modified-closure` in that code?

Comment: Ah, thank you, fixed now, will accept your answer as my SelectDAO was incorrect.